# AS400 - CPF4028 - Öffnen von Teildatei PCOUT in SEQONLY(*NO) geändert

Tags: api, ibm-midrange

I got this error calling the API **QSPOPNSP** to open a file on as400 using c#.

Why does the error occure and how I can prevent it?

Comment: CPF4028 isn't an error ... it's an informational message.  Check out https://ibm.co/2JlQSUZ for details on the parameters and possible error messages.

Comment: Jeah, I know it's not a specific error of QSPOPNSP. First the error isn't listed in the table of API error of this API program and second it's thrown directly in the call directive.

Do I have to do something with the file **before** I try to open it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the mistake. Despite the misleading error message, it was an authorization problem. I wasn't allowed to call this API command.

Thanks